# How to get the number of orders for each category?

Tags: yii2

I have 2 tables.

```
category (id, name, description, keywords, visibility) 
orders (id, category_id, price_id, name, telephone, date, processed)
```

Model Category

```
public static function tableName()
{
    return 'category';
}
public function getOrders()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Orders::className(), ['category_id' => 'id']);
}

function getPrices()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Price::className(), ['category_id' => 'id']);
}
```

and Model Orders

```
public static function tableName()
{
    return 'orders';
}
public function getCategory()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Category::className(), ['id' => 'category_id']);
}


public function getPrice()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Price::className(), ['id' => 'price_id']);
}
```

I want to display the number of orders for each category when displaying categories for statistics. How to do it?

Tree building code

```
<?php  foreach ($cat as $item) :?>
                                        <ul class="treeview">
                                            <?php if ($item['id'] !=  17): ?>
                                                <li><a href="#"><?=$item['name']?> - 3</a>
                                                    <ul>
                                                        <?php  foreach ($price as $itemok) :?>
                                                            <?php if ($item['id'] ==  $itemok['category_id']): ?>
                                                                <li><a href="#"><?=$itemok['name']?></a></li>
                                                            <?php endif; ?>
                                                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </li>
                                            <?php endif; ?>
                                        </ul>
                                    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: add the code where you are iterating on the categories .

Comment: I do not know how to insert a code into the comment

Comment: you should add the code into the question by [**`EDITING`**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50063275/edit) I added an answer below see if it helps

Comment: I added the code for building a category tree and services tree

Comment: i have added the answer below you need to iterate the active record object rather than an array see below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways you can do that see the example below

```
$categories = Category::find()->all();

foreach($categories as $category){
    echo count($category->orders);
    echo $category->getOrders()->count();
}
```

or create a separate method inside the model category

```
public function getOrderCount(){
    return $this->getOrders()->count();
}
```

and then use it like

```
$category->orderCount;
```

Comment: $category->orderCount; 

I understand that it is necessary to add a property to the model? 
Since getOrderCount is the method that you want to call.

Comment: just add the function `getOrderCount()` into you model and use the `Category::find()->all()` to get records from the categories model @EvgeniiDuniak